# Selecting an appending ID attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why does the last 'In Stock' field replaces every other 'In Stock' field when I'm trying to place value on the quantity?

```
<form action="add_sales.php" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover results table-fixed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>In Stock</th>
                <th style="width: 20%">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="warning no-result">
                <td colspan="8"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No Product Found</td>
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
                $exec = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                $a = 1;
                $b = 1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {
                    $product_id = $row['product_id'];
                    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
                    $product_price = $row['sell_price'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $product_quantity = $row['quantity'];
                }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product_id; ?><input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_price; ?></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="hehe" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" id="<?php echo "qtyResult" . $a++; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="qtyBuy[]" id="<?php echo "qtyBuy" . $b++; ?>" onkeyup="updateStock(this, event)"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="addCart" value="Add Items to Cart" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery script. I think the problem is in the `var inStock`'s value. When I change the `var inStock`'s value to a fixed number, it's working fine.

```
function updateStock(obj, event) {
    var inputQty = obj.value;
    var inStock = "<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>";
    $(obj).closest('tr').find('input[id^="qtyResult"]').val(inStock - inputQty);
}
```

[image: Relevant Table Image]

Comment: the function `updateStock` has a php variable which is written once before the html is rendered - use the `event` argument of the function to determine the appropriate value for the field rather than a hardcoded value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$product_quantity` will be set to the last value in the loop.

If you view source and look at the javascript function, you will see it reads:

```
function updateStock(obj, event) {
    var inputQty = obj.value;
    var inStock = "234"; //or whatever the last value was
    $(obj).closest('tr').find('input[id^="qtyResult"]').val(inStock - inputQty);
}
```

As the values can change after the page has loaded (and therefor after php has quit) you should grab the current value from the dom when you need it:

```
function updateStock(obj, event) {
    var inputQty = obj.value;
    var quantityInput = $(obj).closest('tr').find('input[id^="qtyResult"]');
    quantityInput.val(quantityInput.val() - inputQty);
}
```

Comment: Stucked for more than an hour because of this. I can't upvote yet, unfortunately. Thank you!